# How to add a stored procedure using .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .NET Core and used to working with ASP.NET MVC. I am working on a project using .NET Core 2.2 and Entity Framework Core. I am not sure how to add my stored procedure into this project as before I was used to do it through `.edmx` file.

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
        using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {
            //db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var result= db.usp_GetOpenSorts();
            return Json(new { data = results.ToList() });
        }
}
```

This is how I am used to calling my stored procedure before but now I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: There are many great examples and tutorials out there on google search. for example here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a stored procedure by generating an empty migration and adding the following code to it:

```
public partial class MyMigration: Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
-- code here
END
");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]");
    }
}
```